# Why Chosen.js does not work in awsAccordion.js?

Tags: jquery, overflow, accordion, jquery-chosen

I have a problem with select boxes created using [**Chosen.js**](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) inside a list accordion created using [awsAccordion.js](http://code.anotherwebstorm.com/apps/awsaccordion/).
In my website the select works fine inside accordion but when i click on select to select an option i get the drop down hidden (as shown in [*this screenshot*](http://oi47.tinypic.com/154w19s.jpg)) because accordion div is `overflow:hidden`, so i tried to solve this issue with all solutions listed in [Github](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/86) and with this [solution](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/contributor-guide/browser#TOC-Absolutely-positioned-box-inside-a-box-with-overflow%3a-auto-or-hidden) but neither of these works. And when i close an accordion *awsAccordion* crashes.
Why the Chosen doesn't work well inside awsAccordion?

The Fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/8Tcjq/1/**

Thank you for any help!
Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem lies in the source of awsaccordion.

When using a horizontal accordion all `<div/>` children of the `<li/>` get CSS applied to.

```
for (i = 0; i < $(headLis).parent().find('li').length; i++) {
  $(headLis).parent().find('li').eq(i).css({
    'width': settings.cssAttrsHor.liWidth + 'px',
    'height': settings.cssAttrsHor.liHeight + 'px'
  }).find('div').css({
    'left': settings.cssAttrsHor.liWidth + 'px',
    'width': methods.calcDivWidthHor() + 'px',
    'height': settings.cssAttrsHor.liHeight + 'px'
  });
}
```

But this breaks the display of Chosen (and probably a lot of other html placed inside the accordion) as seen in your fiddle.

And what I see when I look at the repository of awsAccordion there are 2 watchers, 3 stars and 3 forks, which I interpret as a not very well tested or widely used library. So I guess the problems are with awsAccordion and not with Chosen.

Comment: Thank you so much, but if i try to change `<div/>` and `<ul/>` and `<li/>` to `<dl>` and `<dt>` and `<dd>` probably it will work.